# awk statement to get output in one line

Tags: awk

Please suggest -

Input File -

```
G238740
G316342
G748951
G952443
G955221
G952842
G767727
G339717
G712953
```

Command i tried:

```
 awk -F";" '{ print "displayName == \""$1"\" " "||" }' input
```

Current output -

```
displayName == "G238740" ||
displayName == "G316342" ||
displayName == "G748951" ||
displayName == "G952443" ||
displayName == "G955221" ||
displayName == "G952842" ||
displayName == "G767727" ||
displayName == "G339717" ||
displayName == "G712953" ||
```

Desired output , How to get output in one single line

```
displayName == "G238740" || displayName == "G316342" || displayName == "G748951"
```

Comment: Change the `ORS` variable to get a different output separator than newline.

Comment: Why do you need `-F";"`? There are no semicolons in the input file.

Comment: or `awk '{ printf "displayName == \"%s\" || ", $1 }' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf` instead of `print`, so it won't add a newline. And then conditionally print the `||` separator on all lines but the first:

```
awk '{printf("%sdisplayName == \"%s\"", (NR == 1 ? "" : " || "), $1)}
    END {print ""}' input
```

Comment: Hi Barmar , Thanks for perfect reply. Thanks a lot.